# Conference session selection via form exclusivity through radio button or jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, forms

My application allows organizations to create events that have sessions in multiple tracks.  These tracks need not be 100% symmetrical (see example image below).

I need to make it so that a single session that might overlap multiple session times, would have a mutual exclusivity-selection relationship.

[image: form example]

In this example, if a registrant selects the Workshop session (from 1-5pm) currently the form prevents the selection of the sessions from 1-2:30pm.

I've achieved this simply by having the name of the radio button for those 3 sessions that all start at 1pm all have the same name.

Ideally, it should also prevent the selection of the sessions from 3-4:30pm.

I cannot use the same solution (having the sessions starting at 3pm have the same name) because then it would prevent registrants from attending a session at 1pm and another at 3pm (w/o selecting the workshop from 1-5pm).

The relevant fields of my session table are as follows:

```
sessionID int
trackID int
eventID int
sessionName varchar
confDay int
start datetime
end   datetime
order int
```

How can I achieve the desired result without an overwhelming amount of code?

The code to render this form can be seen at [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/pcartagena/hq4vjey5/13/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having received an answer, I ended up solving this in a way that I'm not sure is the most elegant.  When I shopped the idea around to some colleagues they understood the problem and my solution wondered if there could be something more elegant but acknowledged that this solution solves the problem.

I welcome alternative approaches.  Here's hoping this helps someone else.

I refer to the session setup above as "asymmetric" because the tracks do not all have the same number of sessions with the exact same timing.

The relevant columns in the session table are listed in the original question. To enable this solution, the following field was added:

```
isLinked int
```

**Note1:** isLinked is either 0 or the sessionID of the not-deleted session that is the one that should appear in the session list with a radio button.

**Note2:** isLinked is set for the deleted and not-deleted sessions that "overlap."

I have a loop that cycles over the conference_days, then tracks, then sessions (in order, up to 5 in a day).  The event setup UI allows a user to soft-delete sessions that are not relevant.

In that UI, the user also specifies if a session will overlap other sessions and, if so, enable the user to set that field for deleted sessions in the same track as well.

The UI for session selection is then facilitated by the following pseudo-code to generate html and javascript to emulate the desired behavior:

```
foreach($conference_days as $day){

    foreach($tracks as $track){

        for($so=1;$so<=5;$so++){
        // $so = session_order

            grab the session for the current $day, track ID, and $so

            if(not soft-deleted && !isLinked) {  // isLinked == 0
                display as normal with all details + radio button

            } elseif(not soft-deleted && isLinked) {
                display as normal with all details + radio button
                also add javascript that when above radio button is selected
                    a variable* number of to-be-created, hidden, radio buttons 
                    (below) are also selected; 
                    *count the isLinked sessions with same ID that are soft-deleted

            } else {
                display nothing, but...
                output a radio button with style.visiblity=hidden named in a 
                    predictable way based on $day, $track, and $so
                add javascript that to monitor changes to the radio selection in 
                this row so it auto-deselects the visible radio button above.
            }
        }
     }
 }
```